# Subnetting with VLSM

Tags: networking, subnet, cisco-packet-tracer

Hello I am new to networking and I am a bit confused. I need to subnet this with VLSM, I think I need 6 subnets if I'm not mistaken. I don't really know how to determine all the hosts needed in each subnet. My network address is 192.168.5.0/24. I hope someone can help me.

This is my project in packet tracer
[image: This is my project in packet tracer]

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to determine the hosts needed in each subnet. Count the number of computers in each VLAN and add one or three addresses for routers (depending on redundancy requirements with CARP/HSRP).

- VLAN 20 is 3 hosts + 1/3 router addresses
- VLAN 30 is 3 hosts + 1/3 router addresses
- VLAN 40 is 6 hosts + 1/3 router addresses
- etc.

Comment: thanks for your answer. And what about the VLAN 10 space then?

Comment: 0. You have no hosts in the VLAN and you didn't specify that it's your management VLAN. Based on the information specified, the VLAN is not needed.